# com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException when compiling from command line

Tags: java, android

I have a small Android application that is failing to compile from command line.  I can build and deploy the application to the emulator in Android Studio without issues, however when I try to build from the command line I get the error below.

```
gradle clean assembleDebug
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   >     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   >     0xffff]: 65536
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I understand it's saying I've exceeded the Android 64k method limit described here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

However why would the application compile fine in Android Studio? Any idea what I'm doing wrong when compiling from the command line?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out I was including all the **Google Play Service** libraries in my dependencies, i.e. in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

I removed that dependency and added each Play Service library separately, i.e.:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

per their documentation:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

That way I'm only including the libraries I use.  Now the app compiles both in **Android Studio** and on the command line.  I assume **Android Studio** replaces the entire Play Services library with what the application needs at compile time which is why I could previously compile in **Android Studio** but not on the command line, but I could not confirm this. Hope this helps someone else.